# Laravel log in authentication even with wrong password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

It's a little bit confusing because I am new to laravel. It always redirect me to the `applicant/login` from the url of the action of the form that should be redirected to `applicant/home` with the correct authentication.

Here's my code in my controller:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{   
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if ($this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
        /* 
        $user = Admin::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first();
        // Authentication passed...
        $this->guard()->loginUsingId($user->id);
        */
         return redirect()->intended('applicant/home');
    }

    return view('applicants.home');
}
```

Here's the code in my form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('/applicants/login') }}">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
        @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
        </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-feedback{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
        @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
        </span>
        @endif

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="checkbox icheck">
                <label>
                   <!--<input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me -->
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you used laravel default authentication?

Comment: Do you have your router middleware defined with auth on the pages where login is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel have auth methods by default.

Make: `php artisan make:auth`

Folders with files will be created.

in

> /resources/views/auth/login.blade.php

you have your login form.

Now your form must looks like here:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
            {!! csrf_field() !!}

            <div class="form-group has-feedback {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Email">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group has-feedback{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <div class="checkbox icheck">
                        <label>
                           <!--<input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me -->
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
            </div>
        </form>
```

And in

> app/http/controllers/auth

you have the

> LoginController.php

, inside the:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
you must have this:

protected $redirectTo = '/home'; home, or what you want;)
}
```

Also, check in web.php (routes file) you have:

```
Auth::routes();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I already figure it how! Thankyousomuch! :)

Comment: @JayzdeVera you're welcome mate. If my answer help you, mark it as correct;) If you have any question of Laravel, you can put the url in comment of this answer and i will try to help you. Happy Code!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this may be help for you :

Simply use laravel default authentication for login and register user like:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Hope this help for you!!!

Answer (score 1):

As @Lluís Puig Ferrer suggested, use Laravel's build in Auth. There is a lot of documentation on that online.

Make sure when you define your routes inside `web.php` to use the `auth middleware`. When a user wants to access a page that uses the `auth middleware` they will either be asked to login or granted access if already logged in

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() { 
    // All the routes that require login authentication
};
```

Comment: I figure it out! :) Thanks btw :)